# How to avoid overwriting a List <Object> inside a for (Object []) with map

Tags: java, spring

I have a list type `List <Object []>` that is dynamically loaded from a database query. How can you correct and avoid that with each iteration of the `For (Object [] ..)` cycle, the data already entered is overwritten by the last value of the map list in `targetList.add (map);`

---

***This is the result of the query, which I am loading from the database***

[view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKPNZ.png)

---

***This is the method where the received list is transformed into a list type Map***

```
@GetMapping("/teacher-social-media3")
public ResponseEntity<?> sqlObjectNative(){

    List<Object[]> listRecibid = teacherSocialMediaServ.sqlObjectMany();
    List<Object> targetList = new LinkedList<Object>();     

    Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>(); /*Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();*/         


    if(listRecibida != null && listRecibida.size()>0 ){   
        for(Object[] object: listRecibida ) {   
            map.put("Id_teacher_social_media", object[0]);              
            map.put("Id_teacher_fk", object[1]);
            map.put("Id_social_media_fk", object[2]);
            map.put("Nickname", object[3]);
            map.put("Id_teacher", object[4]);
            map.put("Name_teacher", object[5]);
            map.put("Id_social_media", object[6]);
            map.put("getName", object[7]);
            map.put("Icon", object[8]);                                             

            targetList.add(map);
        }
    }else {
        map.put("MESSAJE", "THERE ARE NO RECORDS ON BD");
        return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(map, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    } //return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(map, HttpStatus.OK);             
    return new ResponseEntity<>(targetList, HttpStatus.OK);     
}
```

***As you can see the result of the list, all values are overwritten by the last one that had the map list inside the For cycle (Object [] ..)***

```
[
    {
        "Id_teacher_social_media": 12,
        "Id_teacher_fk": 6,
        "Id_social_media_fk": 8,
        "Nickname": "gamers rela",
        "Id_teacher": 6,
        "Name_teacher": "Manuelo",
        "Id_social_media": "man",
        "getName": 8,
        "Icon": "VideoJuegos"
    },
    {
        "Id_teacher_social_media": 12,
        "Id_teacher_fk": 6,
        "Id_social_media_fk": 8,
        "Nickname": "gamers rela",
        "Id_teacher": 6,
        "Name_teacher": "Manuelo",
        "Id_social_media": "man",
        "getName": 8,
        "Icon": "VideoJuegos"
    },
    {
        "Id_teacher_social_media": 12,
        "Id_teacher_fk": 6,
        "Id_social_media_fk": 8,
        "Nickname": "gamers rela",
        "Id_teacher": 6,
        "Name_teacher": "Manuelo",
        "Id_social_media": "man",
        "getName": 8,
        "Icon": "VideoJuegos"
    },
    {
        "Id_teacher_social_media": 12,
        "Id_teacher_fk": 6,
        "Id_social_media_fk": 8,
        "Nickname": "gamers rela",
        "Id_teacher": 6,
        "Name_teacher": "Manuelo",
        "Id_social_media": "man",
        "getName": 8,
        "Icon": "VideoJuegos"
    },
    {
        "Id_teacher_social_media": 12,
        "Id_teacher_fk": 6,
        "Id_social_media_fk": 8,
        "Nickname": "gamers rela",
        "Id_teacher": 6,
        "Name_teacher": "Manuelo",
        "Id_social_media": "man",
        "getName": 8,
        "Icon": "VideoJuegos"
    },
    {
        "Id_teacher_social_media": 12,
        "Id_teacher_fk": 6,
        "Id_social_media_fk": 8,
        "Nickname": "gamers rela",
        "Id_teacher": 6,
        "Name_teacher": "Manuelo",
        "Id_social_media": "man",
        "getName": 8,
        "Icon": "VideoJuegos"
    },
    {
        "Id_teacher_social_media": 12,
        "Id_teacher_fk": 6,
        "Id_social_media_fk": 8,
        "Nickname": "gamers rela",
        "Id_teacher": 6,
        "Name_teacher": "Manuelo",
        "Id_social_media": "man",
        "getName": 8,
        "Icon": "VideoJuegos"
    },
    {
        "Id_teacher_social_media": 12,
        "Id_teacher_fk": 6,
        "Id_social_media_fk": 8,
        "Nickname": "gamers rela",
        "Id_teacher": 6,
        "Name_teacher": "Manuelo",
        "Id_social_media": "man",
        "getName": 8,
        "Icon": "VideoJuegos"
    },
    {
        "Id_teacher_social_media": 12,
        "Id_teacher_fk": 6,
        "Id_social_media_fk": 8,
        "Nickname": "gamers rela",
        "Id_teacher": 6,
        "Name_teacher": "Manuelo",
        "Id_social_media": "man",
        "getName": 8,
        "Icon": "VideoJuegos"
    },
    {
        "Id_teacher_social_media": 12,
        "Id_teacher_fk": 6,
        "Id_social_media_fk": 8,
        "Nickname": "gamers rela",
        "Id_teacher": 6,
        "Name_teacher": "Manuelo",
        "Id_social_media": "man",
        "getName": 8,
        "Icon": "VideoJuegos"
    },
    {
        "Id_teacher_social_media": 12,
        "Id_teacher_fk": 6,
        "Id_social_media_fk": 8,
        "Nickname": "gamers rela",
        "Id_teacher": 6,
        "Name_teacher": "Manuelo",
        "Id_social_media": "man",
        "getName": 8,
        "Icon": "VideoJuegos"
    },
    {
        "Id_teacher_social_media": 12,
        "Id_teacher_fk": 6,
        "Id_social_media_fk": 8,
        "Nickname": "gamers rela",
        "Id_teacher": 6,
        "Name_teacher": "Manuelo",
        "Id_social_media": "man",
        "getName": 8,
        "Icon": "VideoJuegos"
    }
]
```

***Thank you very much for your opinions that you can share !!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instantiate a new HashMap each time, at the beginning of the for loop.

Comment: It would be something like this?   map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();   .I have a doubt, declaring again map = new LinkedHashMap <String, Object> (); Would a new object be being created for each iteration of the for loop (Object [] ...)? ... or is the memory position being replaced? Thank you very much for your important help.